# microsoft navision nav 2009, Shipment date

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

where in micrososft navision nav 2009 will be set the posting date?

I have looked in table 36 - Sales header. But there the posting date will not be set. So in wich table then?

Thank you

[image]

Ok, I found out that in table 37-Sales line there is a function: No.-OnValidate. There I can see the Shipment but only in the grid the shipment date will be filled. But the textbox verzenddatum(shipment date) will not be filled. So how to fill in that textbox with the shipment date? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the standard database (maybe your one is modified) the Shipment Date is set to WORKDATE [(what is WORKDATE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh179538(v=nav.90).aspx) during the creation of the Document (InitRecord function in T36 - Sales Header):

[image: T36InitRecord]

This can be modified later based on the Customer, Shipment Method etc.

But really, you should ask your Dynamics NAV Partner about this.

Cheers!